# How to create formula to produce signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have difficulties to create a formula in MATLAB. Firstly because I don't quite understand about this software.

So I want to ask, for example this question:

```
% b is the input binary bit stream
% f is the frequency of the carrier 
n = length(b); % determine the length of bit stream
t = 0:0.01:n-0.01;   % time axis
for i = 1:n
bw( ((i-1)*100)+1 : i*100 ) = b(i); % loop       
end
carrier = cos(2*pi*f*t); % carrier signal
modulated = bw.*carrier; % modulated signal
```

Plot the time domain for an ASK modulated signal with a carrier signal of `s1(t)=cos(10*pi*t)` and a unipolar Non Return to Zero binary bit stream `m1(t)`

Why we have to use loop? How does the formula can create a signal?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to start from here [how to plot signals in matlab](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4aobgSiajc). by using a loop, the result can be obtained as time(t) varies from 0 to infinity